# VB6 Audit Trail

Tags: vb6

was wondering if anyone had any insight on creating an audit trail process in VB6?

I have an application that gets populated with existing data with the use of 3 or 4 classes. The user can then modify any data they wish on this application. Then the data is saved into tables used for a queue. Basically exact copies of the tables the data came from. My problem is I need to create an audit trail.

What is the best practice for this? Compare every control (text box, radio, check box) on the application which is around 100? Or can I utilize the text_changed event of the text boxes? Really have no idea where to start on this one.

Oh and to make it fun, using a Pervasive DB v9.

Thanks for any help.

Cheers

Comment: Typically, audit trails should be implemented at the database level, not the application level.  If anybody was able to modify the data using anything other than your VB6 app, there would be no audit trail.  Implementing the audit trail at the database level would keep the trail regardless of which application is used.  I'm not familiar with Pervasive DB, but if it supports table triggers, that would be the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

This should always be done inside the DB.

Something like this (cribbed in part from post to the pervasive forum, I haven't actually used Pervasive):

```
create trigger insTrig
before insert on table1
referencing new as new_rec
for each row
insert into table2 values (new_rec.co1,new_rec.col2,new_rec.col3,...)#

create trigger delTrig
before delete on table1
referencing old as new_rec
for each row
insert into table2 values (new_rec.co1,new_rec.col2,new_rec.col3,...)#

create trigger updTrig
after update on table1
referencing new as new_rec
for each row
insert into table2 values (new_rec.co1,new_rec.col2,new_rec.col3,...)#
```